# How to Sort a column in datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, telerik, radgrid

I have a datagrid, which contains two columns.. second column will contain a dropdown .. The dropdown contains all the DB column names and when i select any DB column field from the dropdown then the field will be mapped to first column and the selected field from the dropdown will no longer exists in the dropdown.

when i clear the field from the first column, then the field will again bind to the dropdown, but the field is displaying at the last in the dropdown, so the field should not be displayed at last, it should display in it's previous place(i.e from the place where the field mapped from dropdown).

So can any one please let me know how to handle this is xaml.cs file.. That will be more helpfull for me...Thanks !!!

Initially i have declared an  ObservableCollection OcCols = null;

//Used TableColumnsQuery in swith case case and adding all the column names from the table and then added the columns to OcCols.

TableColumnsQuery is declared as "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM   information_schema.columns WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity')!= 1 and  table_name ="

case "TableColumnsQuery", in the case adding all the columns from the table to OcCols and then adding the OcCols to the grid.
((GridViewComboBoxColumn)this.gridMappings.Columns[2]).ItemsSource = OcCols
Gridmappings is the grid name and second column has the combo box\dropdown which i have xplained earlier. 
so now how to sort the columnfileds in the combobox/dropdown.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you are binding to the dropdown?

Comment: post some code - it will provide a clearer picture

Comment: Hi.. I have added my piece of code above.. thanks !!!